# How to add drop out for the fully connected layer with the TF function fully_connected?

Tags: tensorflow

The tensorflow function mentioned in  [fully_connected](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/fully_connected) has no parameter to add drop out for the last layer. Is there a way ?

Comment: Can you please explain your problem in detail, what you want to do? Usually last layer is the one which predicts some class or value, what do you want to achieve using drop_out there.

Comment: @VivekKumar people have already answered correctly. why still -2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this in this way:

```
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)
```

Please refer: https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros

Answer (score 5):

Please look at tutorial [Deep MNIST for Experts](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.4/get_started/mnist/pros) and source code of [mnist_deep.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/756a7fc6370826bcd3dcd155568011077f9928b1/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_deep.py#L79)

```
# Fully connected layer 1 -- after 2 round of downsampling, our 28x28 image
# is down to 7x7x64 feature maps -- maps this to 1024 features.
with tf.name_scope('fc1'):
    W_fc1 = weight_variable([7 * 7 * 64, 1024])
    b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])

    h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7*7*64])
    h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

# Dropout - controls the complexity of the model, prevents co-adaptation of
# features.
with tf.name_scope('dropout'):
    keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

# Map the 1024 features to 10 classes, one for each digit
with tf.name_scope('fc2'):
    W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 10])
    b_fc2 = bias_variable([10])

    y_conv = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2
```

Or if you want to use `tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected` you can do something like this:

```
h_pool2_flatten = tf.contrib.layers.flatten.flatten(h_pool2)
h_fc1 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(h_pool2_flatten, 1024, scope='fc1')
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
h_fc1_drop = tf.contrib.layers.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)
y_conv = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(h_fc1_drop, 10, activation_fn=None, scope='fc2')
```